# Typesetting a five-number summary

Tags: statistics

I have used a command to typeset a three- or five-number summary in LaTeX, but I can't remember the package name nor find it searching with Google or on StackExchange.  Can you tell me the name of the package and/or the command?

For a three-number summary, it would, IIRC, set the lower hinge (quartile) in a small size font, the median in a bigger font, and the upper hinge in the small size font.

The package documentation also referenced an article that proposed the technique; I'm also looking for it.

@egreg: a three- or five-number summary is simply a way to show certain characteristics of a statistical distribution of a set of numbers. See https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/edu/power-pouvoir/ch12/5214877-eng.htm and https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/fivenum.html, for example.

The contribution of this LaTeX command was to turn the five (or three) numbers into an easily-recognized object through manipulating the size of the glyphs for each number.

Comment: You may be at hand with “three- or five-number summaries”, but you shouldn't think everybody is.

Comment: tl;dr: A 5 number summary is the minimum of the data, the lower quartile, the median, the upper quartile, and the maximum.

Comment: For the 5 number summary, are you also looking for the quartiles to be in a small font?  Are you wanting the min/max to be an even smaller font?

Comment: @teepeemm Yes, the median is in the largest font and each further-out quantile is in a smaller font.  I'm not looking to reimplement the function, though; I'm looking for the existing function, partially because it references an article proposing this.  I tried CTAN with no success.

Comment: I understand wanting a macro, but is there some reason not to write your own?  `\newcommand{\fivenumber}[5]{\tiny#1\small#2\normalsize#3\small#4\tiny#5}` seems like it might do what you want, or at least be a good start.

Comment: Thanks for that as a practical solution, @Teepeemm; I may use or modify it.  As I wrote above, though, the other half (at least) of the reason I'm looking is because I recall it pointing to a journal article that proposed the technique, and I wanted to reference that.